# css3 flexbox limit 4 items per row auto width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]
How can I achieve this using flexbox? Currently, I am using table but I wrap every row in a div to limit it to 5 items only. I want all the items wrapped in one parent only.

I tried flexbox but I want the items width depends on its content. Thank you guys.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
 }
 .flexContainer .item {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
 }
 .flexContainer .item a {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
 <div class="item"><a href="">sdfsf</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdf</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdfd</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdgdf</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">ffffffffff</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdfdg</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dddddddddddddd</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdfdsd</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dsds</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfdsf</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfsdsds</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfssdsfd</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dfsddfdfdf</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dff</a></div>
 <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfdffdfdfdffdfdf</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML too please :)

Comment: Here's some links that may help... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/ http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b4580 https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Comment: @B.V Could you update your question to include the HTML, and ideally make a snippet. It'll be easier to help, thanks

Comment: i want it to be 5 items per row not same width but should take up the the whole width in the container

Comment: @ovokuro Thanks for the response Updated already the post. As you can see it is not 5 items per row.

Comment: If you want a fixed number of items per row, why not make a flex container per row, i.e. group every five items in their own flex container?

Comment: That could work. But I am asking if it is possible to do that all wrapped in one container parent.

Comment: @B.V No, I don't think it's possible to do what you want without creating wrappers for each row.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from this repo https://antibland.github.io/front-end/project_files/css/flexbox_max_items_per_row.html,  it looks like you could do the following in your css:

CSS:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexContainer .item {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
}
```

And this would achieve the desired effect.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexContainer .item {
    padding: 5px;
    flex: 1 1 20%;
}
.flexContainer .item a {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="item"><a href="">sdfsf</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdf</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdfd</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdgdf</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">ffffffffff</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdfdg</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dddddddddddddd</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">fdfdfdsd</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dsds</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfdsf</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfsdsds</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfssdsfd</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dfsddfdfdf</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dff</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dffdfdfdffdfdfdffdfdf</a></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 14-JULY-2017 0829 UTC**

To show a little better the limit of 5 per row using this method, but still being controlled by the width of their content:

```css
 
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexContainer .item {
    padding: 5px;
    flex: 1 1 20%;
}
.flexContainer .item a {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are quite a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are quite a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are quite a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are the biggest divs yet</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are the biggest divs yet</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">I am the daddy of all the divs on this page.</a></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 18-OCT-2019 1909 UTC**

I found out that best practice states using less than available in case of gutters. I have updated the code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexContainer .item {
    padding: 5px;
    flex: 1 1 17%;
}
.flexContainer .item a {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we're short</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are quite a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are quite a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are quite a bit bigger</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are the biggest divs yet</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">we are the biggest divs yet</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">I am the daddy of all the divs on this page.</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the width to be auto in flex: 1 1 20% but it should have 5 items per row just like the image attached in the post.

Comment: The last option in the flex CSS item is not exactly width per se... it is [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).  It basically sets the initial size of each flex item.  By setting it to 20%, you are limiting each item to 1/5 of the available box width, or 5 items per row.  If you make this auto, you are letting the number of total items set the limit, essentially limiting them by content only.  This last bit is why the last box in my example flows out of the flex row into the next, because the content is so long, it cannot fit in the available 20% space.